Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Add Email & SMS subscriber into a list
I am trying to add Email & SMS subscriber into a list, I've done it for Email alone but now I was asked to integrate for SMS Marketing as well.
    <header>
            <fueloauth>YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN</fueloauth>
    </header>
    <body>
        <createrequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <objects xsi:type="Subscriber">
                <objectid xsi:nil="true"></objectid>
                <emailaddress>help@example.com</emailaddress>
                <subscriberkey>help@example.com</subscriberkey>
                <smsaddress>+923212345678</smsaddress>
                <lists>
                    <id>12345</id>
                    <objectid xsi:nil="true"></objectid>
                </lists>
            </objects>
        </createrequest>
    </body>
</envelope>

I am trying this xml to add subscriber into a list, It's working except for smsaddress. I need help adding SMS Number along with the email into a list.
Any help regarding this case would be appreciated.
Regards

mobile connect does not use this object

There is no such property as SMSAddress in the Subscriber object.
I believe you should try using PrimarySMSAddress instead.
